# undefined method `error_on' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm getting this error after running my specs, i have a file called "validations.rb" inside my /support directory and inside the spec_helper.rb there is this line

```ruby
    Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

so it should include my validations.rb file, but i still get the error for undefined method, what am I doing wrong?

**validations.rb**

```ruby
module ::ActiveModel::Validations
  def errors_on(attribute)
    self.valid?
    [self.errors[attribute]].flatten.compact
  end
  alias :error_on :errors_on
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine `errors_on` as `self.errors_on`

Comment: i did change def errors_on to def self.errors_on and i still get the NoMethod error :/

Comment: I am stupid, I did user = FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid and because of that I got the NoMethod error because user is not an ActiveModel class